# derived category of equivariant coherent sheaves and fixed points

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, ag.algebraic-geometry

The K-group $K^T(X)$ of $T$(torus)-equivariant coherent sheaves on a variety $X$ is isomorphic to $K^T(X^T)$, that of the fixed point locus via the inclusion homomorphism, when we tensor the quotient field of the representation ring $R(T)$ of $T$.

Is there a similar result for $D_T(Coh X)$ and $D_T(Coh X^T)$, derived categories of $T$-equivariant coherent sheaves ? I do not know even how to formulate `the quotient field of $R(T)$' in the derived category case.

Comment: This seems like exactly the sort of thing that ought to be one of the main results in the paper of Goresky-Kottwitz-MacPherson.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to extract the kind of statement you're asking for; it would be very interesting if someone can give a precise answer.  They do give a localization-type theorem for an element of the equivariant derived category in (7.8), but only after taking cohomology.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that to me at all.  Is there anything about coherent sheaves in GKM?

Comment: @Ben, you're absolutely right, somehow I missed the salient word "coherent" in the question.  But even for constructible sheaves, is there a localization statement at the level of derived categories?